# VB Asp.net Passing Parameter to Subquery or Better Solution?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

Environment: Visual Basic Asp.net connected to an Access database

Okay, putting together a Select statement for a database I'm working on and I'm stumped. Hopefully one of you can come up with a solution!

```
Laying out the problem:
Table Name: CONTACTS
Field: ContactID (primary key, autonumber)
Field: UserName [this is being used to identify the user easily from Asp.net]

Table Name: APPLICANT
Field: ContactID (primary foreign)
Field: JobID (primary foreign)

Table Name: JOB
Field: JobID (primary key, autonumber)
Field: Description
Field: Class
Field: Type
```

What I need is * from JOB for the Job's which they HAVEN'T applied for. When they have applied for a job, it is reflected by the combined keys of ContactID and JobID in the APPLICANT table.

I can accomplish this in Access by two queries:

```
SELECT Applicant.JobID
FROM Contacts INNER JOIN Applicant ON Contacts.[ContactID] = Applicant.[ContactID]
WHERE (((Contacts.UserName)='Test002'));

SELECT Job.JobID, Job.Description, Job.JobType, Job.JobClass
FROM Job LEFT JOIN [Applicant Query] ON Job.[JobID] = [Applicant Query].[JobID]
WHERE ((([Applicant Query].JobID) Is Null));
```

Where [Applicant Query] refers to the first query, of course.

Now, because UserName is being used to Identify the User, it has to be included in the query, which is where the difficulty is. In Visual Studio, I know how to pass parameters to the Select command. However, I don't seem to be able to pass parameters to a subquery. Just to be exhaustive in my explanation, 'Test002' is the part that I'm looking to replace with the parameter.

I'm hoping you guys know a way to solve this, or, failing that, a genius way to circumvent the problem entirely. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about combining this into a single query by using a subquery? It would look something like this:

```
SELECT Job.JobID, Job.Description, Job.JobType, Job.JobClass
FROM Job 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Applicant.JobID
  FROM Contacts INNER JOIN Applicant ON Contacts.[ContactID] = Applicant.[ContactID]
  WHERE ((Contacts.UserName)='Test002')) AS subqry
ON Job.[JobID] = [subqry].[JobID]
WHERE (([subqry].JobID) Is Null));
```

That's the same logic, just using a single query instead of two queries.